# Center a div unequally using CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am centering a `div` inside another `div` using a flexbox. Think of a dialog window that pops up in the center of the screen when needed.

It works fine, however it would look much better if the space above and below the dialog was not exactly equal, having 40% of the remaining space be above and 60% below the dialog. It gets tricky because the dialog height varies with the amount of text inside.

So for example, if the browser height is 1000px, and the dialog window height is 400px, I want the remaining vertical space (600px) to be 240px above and 360px below the dialog.

I could do it with JavaScript, but I'm curious if there is some clever way with CSS. I tried adding a bottom margin to the `#dialogBox` `div`, but that doesn't work when the dialog height is getting near the browser height.

```css
#dialogBoxPanel {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#dialogBox {
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialogBoxPanel">
  <div id="dialogBox">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need the outer panel to cover the whole viewport ? If not, I'd go with the solution from https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/, section "Both Horizontally and Vertically / Is the element of unknown width and height?", and modify the translate percentage values. (And even if you do need the parent full viewport size [backdrop?], you should be able to combine both - do away with the flex stuff, rest stays.)

Comment: Yea I have a dimming effect on the outer panel so it needs to cover the whole viewport. But I could add another DIV inside of it, and your solution would work fine. Thanks 04FS!

Comment: For the sake of accuracy, you're talking about vertical alignment, not centering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use pseudo element and column direction to simulate the white space. Simply adjust the `flex-grow` of the pseudo element to control how much free space each one should take. Equal flex-grow will give equal space:

```css
#dialogBoxPanel {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* the center */
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

#dialogBox {
  width: 350px;
  border:1px solid;
}

#dialogBoxPanel:before {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:4;
}
#dialogBoxPanel:after {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:6;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialogBoxPanel">
  <div id="dialogBox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc hendrerit diam eu nisl fringilla ornare. Pellentesque aliquam quam et tellus egestas sodales. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin bibendum,</div>
</div>
```

You can also use `2` and `3`. We simply need to keep the same ratio:

```css
#dialogBoxPanel {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* the center */
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

#dialogBox {
  width: 350px;
  border:1px solid;
}

#dialogBoxPanel:before {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:2;
}
#dialogBoxPanel:after {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:3;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialogBoxPanel">
  <div id="dialogBox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc hendrerit diam eu nisl fringilla ornare. Pellentesque aliquam quam et tellus egestas sodales. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin bibendum,</div>
</div>
```

Another idea is to use top value equal to `40%` and rectify the position with translate (same logic with the `50%` when centring)

```css
#dialogBoxPanel {
  position: absolute;;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* the center */
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

#dialogBox {
  position:relative;
  top:40%;
  width: 350px;
  transform:translateY(-40%);
  margin:auto;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialogBoxPanel">
  <div id="dialogBox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc hendrerit diam eu nisl fringilla ornare. Pellentesque aliquam quam et tellus egestas sodales. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin bibendum,</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Temani! Both solutions work perfectly, and seem identical except for the special case where the dialog is taller than the browser. The first solution keeps the top of the dialog aligned with the top of the browser, cropping at the bottom. The second crops both bottom and top. Just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 5):

This solution uses `display: grid`, it's a new feature so be sure to check the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) and [click here](https://learncssgrid.com/) to learn more.

This is the line that controls the top and bottom spaces:

`grid-template-rows: 40fr [content-start] auto [content-end] 60fr;`

The snippet text content can be edited for you to check that the box keeps centered even if the height changes.

```css
#dialogBoxPanel {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 40fr [content-start] auto [content-end] 60fr;
}
#dialogBox {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 350px;
    grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialogBoxPanel">
   <div id="dialogBox" contenteditable>Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would consider the use of `4fr auto 6fr`. What you have works but wiith some overflow since 40% + 60% + 1fr will always be bigger than 100% and you are centring so the overlow will be split equally from the top and bottom: https://jsfiddle.net/cobutn0e/2/. You will also notice that it's not 100% like expected

Comment: I just changed the 1fr to auto, I'd rather leave it as % to match the question values. Thanks a lot for pointing the error!

Comment: auto and 1fr will give the same result in your case, the issue is the use of percentage; `1fr=minmax(auto,1fr)` and in your case it will fall to `auto` as there is no free space since 40%+60% =100% (that's why you will always have overflow)

Comment: here is another fiddle to illustrate my point: https://jsfiddle.net/cobutn0e/3/  notice how the 3 first are the same, the third one is falling to 0 and the last one is what I suggested

Comment: Now I get it, makes sense. Gonna use 40fr and 60fr since it's the same in the end of the day. Thanks again for taking your time to teach me!

Answer (score 5):

You can add spacers divs and set the flex-grow with 4:6 ratio.

```css
#dialogBoxPanel {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;

  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#dialogBox {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.spacer-top{
  flex-grow: 4;
}
.spacer-bottom{
  flex-grow: 6;
```

```html
<div id="dialogBoxPanel">
  <div class="spacer-top"></div>
  <div id="dialogBox">Text</div>
  <div class="spacer-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only now saw @Temani Afif's answer, but it works the same with "after" and "before"

Answer (score 0):

Simple way using position and margin, i assumed that your dialog height is always 40% of browser height.

```
.modal{
            max-height:50%;
            width:400px;
            margin: 10% auto 5% auto;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            right:0;
            left:0;
            overflow-y: auto
        }
        .modal-body{
            background-color: beige;
            padding: 20px;
            line-height: 21px
        }
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal">
 <div class="modal-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi welcome, next time please read the question carefully, it states: "the dialog height varies with the amount of text inside."

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto - now controlling it via max height in percentage, as leaving it without height will not solve the questions purpose of top and bottom space aesthetic.